# Django: something wrong with ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have a model with `ManyToManyField`. This field has `limit_choices_to` attribute which is set to callable. My problem is that this callable isn't called **every time** form is validated/instantiated in my view. It is called only once, after making changes in code. Django says:

> If a callable is used for limit_choices_to, it will be invoked **every
>   time a new form is instantiated**. It may also be invoked when a model
>   is validated, for example by management commands or the admin. The
>   admin constructs querysets to validate its form inputs in various edge
>   cases multiple times, so there is a possibility your callable may be
>   invoked several times.

Any ideas why it doesnt working?

My code:

```
def limit_name_choices():
    if Name.objects.count():
        return {"pk__gt": Name.objects.last().pk}
    else:
        return {}

class Robject(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(to=Project, null=True, blank=True)
    names = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Name",
        related_name="robject_names",
        limit_choices_to= limit_name_choices,
        blank=True
    )

    [...]
```

**SOLVED:**
Bug was fixed in 1.11.3 release.

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code so it's mostly a wild guess but from the behaviour it looks like you set your `limit_choices_to` to the result of calling your function (or whatever callable), ie `limit_choices_to=yourcallable()`, not to the callable itsef ie `limit_choices_to=yourcallable` (note the absence of parens in the first case).

Comment: I added code to post

Comment: Ok your code seems mostly fine. But you may want to check your Django version, there's been a bug with this feature recently cf https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28345

Comment: Thank you so much! I find out that bug was fixed in 1.11.3 release.